# Oracle Apex list manager/list control?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have a query which gets me all groups the current user belongs to. Currently, I am able to use it as a LOV in a Select List control. From what I understand, the only "list box"-type control in Apex is List Manager and Shuttle. Can't seem to get either to work. Shuttle kind of works, but only shows one value, or values just on the left side.

Can you provide with an example how to set it up properly? Either a 2side shuttle or a list manager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shuttle has a list of values and its value is a concatenated list of selected LOV values, separated by colons.

Suppose the LOV contains the values:

```
Display Return
------- ------
Apple   A
Banana  B
Cherry  C
Damson  D
Egg     E
```

If you want it to show initially with Banana and Damson already selected then set the shuttle value to:

```
B:D
```

Once the user has moved items about the value will change to e.g.

```
A:C:D
```

You would then need to parse that value to get the individual values.  The utility function [apex_util.string_to_table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_util.htm#CHDFEEJD) is ideal for that.  (There is a nice example in the linked documentation).

I am not familiar with List Manager but from a quick try it appears to work on the same basis as above.